# Pyhton csv reader: loop over csv files

Tags: python, loops, csv, csvreader

I have several csv files that are named: `list_csv_X` with X going from 0 to 5. I would like to do a loop to read them with Python.

I am currently doing it manually:

```
for filepath in list_csv_0:
    with open(filepath,'r',encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as csvfile:
        BLABLABLA
for filepath in list_csv_1:
    with open(filepath,'r',encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as csvfile:
        BLABLABLA
for filepath in list_csv_2:
    with open(filepath,'r',encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as csvfile:
        BLABLABLA
```

How can I do it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could use an f-string to construct the filenames in a loop

Comment: use pyhton glob or Path.glob with a file pattern "lst_csv_*.csv" in order to get all csv files. then open them as you do...

Comment: is `list_csv_0` a list of filenames or a single filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If I understand correctly, each of your 6 items is a *list of filenames*, yes?

I am assuming that, because you are doing this, and saying that it currently works:

```
for filepath in list_csv_0:
```

That would lead to an error, if `list_csv_0` were a filename, because `filepath` values would be individual characters of the filename, not ever a whole filename.

#### You can loop over the lists

```
list_csvs = [list_csv_0,list_csv_1,list_csv_2,list_csv_3,list_csv_4,list_csv_5]

for list_csv in list_csvs:
    for filepath in list_csv:
        with open(filepath,'r',encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as csvfile:
            BLABLABLA
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a simple *for* loop and an f-string as follows:

```
def process(filename):
    with open(filename) as indata:
        pass # process file here

for fileno in range(6):
    with open(f'list_csv_{fileno}') as catalogue:
        for line in catalogue:
            process(line.strip())
```

Comment: This solution does not work in my case. I think that I need an extra loop: in my case, each `list_csv_X` file contain a list of path toward csv file that have different name:
For instance `list_csv_0` contains
`/home/path0/x01_200000.csv
/home/path0/x02_200000.csv
/home/path0/x03_200000.csv`
and `list_csv_1` contains
`/home/path1/x01_300000.csv
/home/path1/x02_300000.csv
/home/path1/x03_300000.csv`

Both the path and the file name are modified.

Comment: @Martin7 That wasn't clear (to me) in your original question. See edit. This kind of pattern is often well-suited to multiprocessing/multithreading otherwise each file will be processed linearly. Something for you to think about